# fullcalendar time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, fullcalendar

Good afternoon, I know that this topic has been discussed on previous ocassions, nevertheless despite the different threads I still can't solve my problem. I am using the full calendar provided at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/, and they have two ways of displaying time, "10:30a"-"7p", for example. I want the time displayed on the calendar of events that are not full day, in a format "12:00 pm" or "12:00 am". The problem i'm having is, when you download the fullcalendar you have several files:

fullcalendar.js, fullcalendar.css, fullcalendar.min.js, fullcalendar.print.css, gcal.js, jquery-1.9.1.min, jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min

I tried what other threads suggest, which is a change in the fullcalendar.js at the time format and setdefault methods but to no avail. I can even delete the file "fullcalendar.js" and my test still works just fine. I want to know why is this and if the time format is not managed there, where is it managed? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what files you have included in your code? Also, please post your FullCalendar initialization code.

Comment: I included fullcalendar.js, fullcalendar.css, fullcalendar.min.js, fullcalendar.print.css, jquery-1.9.1.min.js, jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js. The initialization code just has one test event with title, start and end date and allday set to false. The event is displayed correctly, but the time remains 7p or 10:30a ( for example )

Answer (score 11):

Use this and it's going to work:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 timeFormat: 'hh:mm a'
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using timelineDay view, I found out that this setting will change the time format:

```
slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm"
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem before,  this will solve your problem

if you are using **version 4**, add this object to your fullcalender's object

```
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "2-digit",
  meridiem: "short",
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
axisFormat: 'h:mm a'
```

Answer (score 3):

First I think you are confused with so many files, but basically you need only need the minified of the javascript and css to make it work.

Second, I had the same problem when displaying the time correctly. This is what I did, it is a bit of workaround but it worked for me, sorry if its dirty.

When you initialise the calendar you have to put the option for the timeformat so it shows the minutes even if its rounded hours.

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({ timeFormat: 'h:mm t' });
```

Then it was appearing only the "a" or "p" not "am" or "pm" so I used a little bit of CSS magic to add the "m" at the end, I created the rule:

```
.fc-time:after { content: "m"; }
```

now you might mess up with the week view so you add the rule

```
.fc-axis.fc-time:after { content: " "; }
```

And now hopefully you have it the way you want.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

in *fullcalendar v3*, they use ***moment.js*** to format time,
you can format using,
timeFormat: 'h:mm A', you can change between quote with input in this [moment js docs page](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 0):

fullcalendar allows you to change the default times by setting the time format (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/). Probably better than changing the source code.

I think the reason your solution isn't working is because you are including fullcalendar.js and fullcalendar.min.js. These files contain the same code, the second one being a minified version of the first. Minified files are typically used in deployed versions of sites whereas the other version is used in development. So if you want to make changes don't include the minified version

Answer (score 0):

In your scheduler.fullcalendar.js file look for the **events:[],** and under it add this line  **timeFormat: 'hh:mm A',** 
it will show time like this 10:20 PM
and if u want to show time like this 10:20 Pm use small **a**